# What are the different theories related to Ramayana?

Tags: ramayana

Good evening folks. I just got a bit interested in our epic `The Ramayana`. Turns out our renowned scholar **Mr. DevDutt Pattnaik** disclosed that there are many forms of Ramayana. With so many renowned scholars on Hinduism, I am really excited to know how they vary from each other. Some I could hear about was that Ravana is given as the role of antagonist in one of the `Ramayana`.

Would anyone explain how many forms we have of Ramayana? And are they really differing from each other like I explained above?? 
Thank you.

Comment: "I am really excited to know how they vary from each other" - this is too broad. [Many Ramayanas: The Diversity of a Narrative Tradition in South Asia edited by Paula Richman](https://publishing.cdlib.org/ucpressebooks/view?docId=ft3j49n8h7;brand=eschol) is a good starting point.

Comment: Not sure about how many forms r there but why they differ is explained in https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23817/12304