# Sita- Avatar of Lakshmi goddess or next birth of a pious woman?

Tags: ramayana, avatars, goddess, shloka, sita

In Ramayana, I have read somewhere that Sita is Avatar of a pious women who was a devotee of God Vishnu in previous birth. Please let me know the related sloka from Ramayana?

Comment: @UdayKrishna yes I agree, but I have heard that Ravan got a curse from a pious women that he will be killed by Rama and she will be his wife...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is **Both**.

Sita was incarnation of Godess Lakshmi. But, Sita whom Ravana abducted was avatar of a pious women (Vedvati) who was a devotee of God Vishnu.

---

This is what Ravana suspects in **Valmiki Ramayan: Yuddha Kanda: Sarga 60**:

> शप्तोऽहम् वेदवत्या च यदा सा धर्षिता पुरा || [६-६०-१०](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga60/yuddhasans60.htm#Verse10)
>
> सेयम् सीता महाभागा जाता जनकनन्दिनी |
>
> [Ravana:] Further, I was formerly cursed by Vedavati when she was humiliated by me. The same **Vedavati** is born as the highly fortunate Seetha the daughter of Janaka.

And this is confirmed in **Valmiki Ramayan: Uttar Kanda: Sarga 17**:

> [image: Sita was incarnation of Vadavati]
>
> O Lord, this is she (Vedavati) that hath been born as the daughter of king Janaka, thy wife, O mighty armed one. Thou are the eternal Vishnu. ~[English translation source](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-17)

---

But, this doesn't mean that Sita was not incarnation of Goddess Lakshmi. See the below Shlokas:

**Valmiki Ramayan: Yuddha Kanda: Sarga 117**:

> सीता लक्ष्मीर्भवान् विष्णुर्देवः कृष्णः प्रजापतिः || [६-११७-२८](https://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga117/yuddhasans117.htm#Verse28)
>
> वधार्थं रावणस्येह प्रविष्टो मानुषीं तनुम् |
>
> [Lord Brahma:] Seetha is no other than Goddess Lakshmi (the divine consort of Lord Vishnu), while you are Lord Vishnu. You are having a shining dark-blue hue. You are the Lord of created beings. For the destruction of Ravana, you entered a human body here, on this earth.

This is enough and no other proof needed because this is confirmed by Lord Brahma himself.

However it's further confirmed in **Valmiki Ramayan: Uttar Kanda** too:

Uttar Kanda Ref 1:

> [image: Sita was incarnation of Lakshmi]

Uttar Kanda Ref 2:

> [image: Sita was incarnation of Lakshmi]

---

Now, the biggest Question is how to handle this? In such scenarios, we generally have 3 answers:

- this might be due to interpolation or
- this might be due to [Kalpa Bheda](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23817/12304) or
- may be we are missing some dots that means this should be dived deep.

I think option 3 is relevant here because Kalpa Bheda should not be the case in the same scripture and interpolation might be there in Uttar Kanda but we have references from Yudha Kanda too.

This is what [Skanda Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/skanda_purana/padmavati_becomes_consort_of_lord_hari.html) says in this regard:

> [Lord Varaha said--]: In Treta yuga, when I had incarnated as Ram, Ravan had deceitfully abducted my consort--Sita. But fortunately she was not Sita but Agni's consort Swaha. Before this incident could occur, Agni had already taken Sita to Patalloka and kept his own wife 'Swaha' in her place. Actually, Agni's consort 'Swaha' was 'Vedavati' in her previous birth. So, in reality Ravan had abducted Vedavati instead of Sita. Later on, I thanked Agni and promised him that I would make Vedavati my consort in Kali yuga. The same Vedavati has taken birth as Padmavati.

Answer (score 1):

Let me show something interesting about our supreme goddess shri janaknandini sarkar. Most of the people think her as laxmi but truth is something else.

**Valmiki Ramayan.: Yuddha Kanda: Sarga 117.:**

> *सीता लक्ष्मीर्भवान् विष्णुर्देवः कृष्णः प्रजापतिः || ६-११७-२८*
>
> *वधार्थं रावणस्येह प्रविष्टो मानुषीं तनुम् |*

**Translation.:**

> ***[Lord Brahma:] Seetha is no other than Goddess Lakshmi (the divine consort of Lord Vishnu), while you are Lord Vishnu. You are having a shining dark-blue hue. You are the Lord of created beings. For the destruction of Ravana, you entered a human body here, on this earth.***

**Valmiki Ramayan 5.52.34.:**

> *यां सीतेत्यभिजानासि येयं तिष्ठति ते गृहे।*
>
> *कालरात्रि इति तां विद्धि सर्वलंकाविनाशनीम्।।*

**Translation.:**

> ***O ravan! Whom you have taken as hostage, that maa sita is none other than kalratri (maa kali) herself.***

Now the question arises that if maa sita is laxmi, then why she is hailed as kalratri here?

**Valmiki Ramayan 2.44.15.:**

> *सुर्यस्यापि भवत् सुर्यो ह्यग्नेरग्नि प्रभोः प्रभुः।*
>
> *श्रियः श्रीश्चभवेद्ग्य्रा कीर्त्या कीर्तिः क्षमाक्षमा।।*
>
> *देवतं देवतानांच भुतानां भुतं रुत्तमः।*
>
> *तस्य के हृयगणा देवि देशेव्याप्यथवा वने।।*

**Translation.:**

> ***Shri Ram is sun of sun, Agni of Agni, Prabhu of Prabhu (narayan of narayan), maa Sita is laxmi of laxmi, kirti of kirti and kshama of kshama.***

That means one thing maa sita is actually adi jagatjanni.
Confirmed by **rudrayamal tantra.:**

> *सर्वदेवम समुत्पन्ना सर्वदेवमयी ईश्वरी।*
>
> *सर्वपोरूषवल्ली च सर्वधर्म अधिकारिणी।।*

**Translation.:**

> ***~ Maa Sita is the Goddess  from whom all the gods  originates and contains all the gods. She is the one who grants porush (धर्म, अर्थ, काम, मोक्ष) of all men and the authority of all religions.***

**Maha sundari tantra.:**

> *आद्या सा प्रकृति सीता आद्यस्तु पुरुषोत्तम।*
>
> *गुणातीतो भवान्नित्यो नित्यभुता सनातनी।।*

**Translation.:**

> ***That first nature (आदि प्रकृति) is Sita and the first is the best of men.( श्रीराम ही आदि पुरुषोत्तम हैं). Transcendental to the modes of nature, Thou art eternal, ever-being, eternal.***

**Maha ramayan.:**

> *जानक्यांश आदि संभुतानेक ब्रह्माण्डकारिणी।
> सा मुलप्रकृतिर् ज्ञेयो महामाया स्वरुपिणी।।*

**Translation.:**

> ***All shaktis have originated from Maa Sita’s ansh kala and she playfully creates infinte universes. Sarveshwari adijagadamba maa Sita is adidevi of all shaktis and hence called as mool prakruti and is independent ruler of all.***