# Which period did Lord Vishnu descend to Tirupathi as Venkateshwara?

Tags: venkateshwara, tirupati

There's a famous story about this when Rishis were performing yagam for welfare of the people in Kaliyuga, Maharishi Bhirgu hit Lord Vishnu's chest on seeing who's the supreme. Upon hitting Vishnu's chest, MahaLakshmi got angry with the Lord and went out of Vaikuntha and descended to Earth as Padmavathy.

Now my question is, in which Kalpa/Manvantara/Mahayuga it happened? Which Purana has reference to this story?

Comment: Kaliyuga...Skanda Purana... for Lord's/Padmavati's manifestation.. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28358/12304 Do you want to know timeline for Bhrigu's test instead...? Both need not to be same...

Comment: So @YDS Lord Balaji was already in previous Manu too?

Comment: Why did you delete the same question worded differently and ask it as a new one?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma - There was no response.

Comment: You can always edit or improve with helpful edits. If you self delete your questions again and again, you would get a ban of asking. Don't do that again. If there was no response, offer a bounty on it.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma - Okay!