# How do Shaivas view and interpret the Ramayana and Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, shaivism, smriti

Do Shaivas accept that Rama and Krishna were incarnations of Vishnu?

How do Shaivas view and interpret these Itihasas?

Comment: They don't interpret Itihasas, Ramayana and Mahabharata, because those scriptures are not of their interest. Shaiva scriptures are of their interest.

Comment: By the way, it is a common misconception among some Hindus that Shaiva Puranas such as Shiva Purana represent a scripture of interest to traditional Shaivas. As far as I heard Shiva Purana and other Puranas were not of interest to old Shaiva traditions, and they became of interest only in recent time, perhaps in a past couple of centuries or so.

Comment: like Vaishnavas interpret Shiva Mahapurana

Comment: @brahmajijnasa so which is the main scripture of Shaivism?

Comment: @RishX Shaivism has several different traditions, and in each they could be studying different scriptures. I haven't studied much of Shaivism, so you better ask someone who have.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa maybe that's why I find studying Shaivism so difficult. I can find Advaita or Vaishnava scriptures so easily. Infact they have common like Bhagavada Gita and Bhagavatam. Idk if Shiva Purana holds similar status for all Shaiva sects. Even I am more familiar with Vaishnavism specifically Gaudiya Vaishnavism due to this reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per **Shiva Purana: PART TWO RUDRA SAMHITA: SATI KHAND: Chapter 24**,

> [Lord Shiva said to Sati:]
>
> 39. The fair-complexioned one is younger brother Laxman, the incarnation of Shesha. The elder brother is complete **incarnation of Vishnu**. He is called Rama.

So, you can see that Shiva Purana (important scripture for Shaivas) portraits Rama as an incarnation of Vishnu.

Also, as mentioned in [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23817/12304), Ramcharitmanas itself is a narration of Parvati's Qs and Shiva's answers only. And, at many places, Ramcharitmanas portraits Rama as Vishnu's incarnation.

Comment: Shiva said "he **was** his deity". Means earlier he was but not now?

Comment: @Rishabh This is due to the use of [Reported speech](https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/tense-changes-when-using-reported-speech/) as tense changes when reported-speech is used....

Comment: @Rishabh Anyway I hv removed irrelevant and debate inviting part ;)