# Why are Puranas silent on events taking place in previous Kalyugs or events of 8th Manvantara from previous Kalpas?

Tags: puranas, kalpa

As seen in questions and answers [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29643/does-kalpa-bheda-explanation-for-reconciling-different-narrative-in-puranas-have), [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10584/how-does-the-names-and-events-reoccur-in-different-manvantara-or-kalpa-or-differ) and [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21446/is-each-of-the-18-mahapurans-related-to-a-different-kalpa), Puranas attribute the differences in their contents to different Kalpas. However if that is indeed the case, why don't we ever read about events taking place in Kalyugs of previous Mahayugas,Manvantaras or Kalpas. Is it because of lack of events in Kalyugs that can help us in spiritual development ? 
Also there is no mention of events taking place in 8th and later Manvantaras from previous Kalpas. Any reasons ? Can it be that verses in the couple of Puranas that  match different Puranas with Kalpas are spurious ?

Comment: Kali yuga is only 10% of time of the entire maha-yuga, and as you said, even for most of kali yuga people are just materialistic. Most of the significant stories happen in previous yugas. Also, there are a few significant stories that do happen in kali yuga like parikshit, janamejaya's snake sacrifice, buddha avatar, etc.

Comment: @Ikshvaku - I would imagine Adi Shankaracharya, Ramana Maharishi etc stories from previous kalpas will be included