# Story of jaya vijaya and King Pratap bhanu

Tags: scripture, vishnu, ravana, ramcharitmanas, tulasi

I was reading through Ramcharitmanas of Goswami Tulsidas Ji.

I read the story of Raja Pratap Bhanu and he becoming Ravana in the next birth.

I wondered, how is that possible when we know that Jay Vijaya was supposed to take 3 births and we clearly know now what were those births

My question is, how come Raja Pratap Bhanu became Ravana? It was Jaya Vijaya who had to be incarnated as Ravana then how come Raja Pratap Bhanu came into the picture.

Please explain.

Comment: Tulsi das ji has listed down many stories of Ravan birth, and Rama birth. This is to signify that there are many Ramayans, and this cycle has happened many times in past (in his own words)

Comment: Can you give exact "doha"  where this is said.

Comment: @hanugm why did you remove ramayana tag ?

Comment: I think that Ramcharitmanas is more apt for this question since you are mentioned in this question. Any issue?

Comment: Ok got it. No issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the expression "kalpa bheda" mean?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23735/what-does-the-expression-kalpa-bheda-mean)

Answer (score 0):

I have a same question and I tried to research a bit and sharing a summary of what I found till now - as close to what sbharti said, there are primarily 2 stories of Ravana's past, one beling Jay/Vijaya and the other being King Bhanupratap. It seems Tulsidas Ramayan and other stories indicate the possibility of parallel universe and multiple phases leading to a common conclusion...

Interesting fact among all is, how even after being cursed to be born in rakshasha kul, Ravana behaved atrocious and sinful life, however his brother Vibhishana led a life of nobility and dharam even though he lived among the company of pervert rakshasas.
Vibhishana in my opinion is one of the great characters to learn from on how to lead a life and stay on path of dharma even when time and surroundings are not in your favor and filled with negative influences.
refer to this link which somewhat explains a different perspective too:
https://www.vedadhara.com/who-was-ravana-in-his-previous-birth

Jai Shri Ram!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).