# If a Purana Contradicts Another Purana

Tags: scripture, puranas, contradiction, exegesis

If a Purana contradicts another Purana, how do we know which one to go with?

Comment: can you give an example of contradiction.

Comment: The difference in stories can be due to [kalpa bheda](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23817/12304) ..hence both valid, you can go with either one...but if it's related to some DOs/DON'Ts then may be it ll depend on context....